# How do I get a variable from an extended controller?

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5

I have this base controller:

```
abstract class ApiController extends BaseController {

use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;
public function __construct()
{
    try {
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Response::json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], HttpResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
}
```

How do I get the $user variable in child controllers? Please provide an example child controller if possible.

Comment: Assign $user to an instance property, then access it from the child with $this->propertyName.

Comment: $user variable is only available in the context of the ApiController __construct method. For it to available in the whole class, and classes extending it, you must define $user as class property and use it like $this->user. This is the same way it can be accessed in child controllers (if property is defined as public or protected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

```
abstract class ApiController extends BaseController {

  use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;

  protected $user; // or public
  public function __construct()
  {
    try {
        $this->user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Response::json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], HttpResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
class Ctrl extends ApiController
{
  public function whatever()
  {
    echo $this->user;
  }
}
```

Last but not least: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/oo-php-part-1-oop-in-full-effect

Happy coding !